# What is the fastest way of replacing DOM element(jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, element

My application is a real-time apps using ajax environment. It is a live picking of schedule. The users want see the available slot in real-time way. such that they can see other ticking schedule. And i'm using ajax to replace the element with the new one.
Example:

```
$.get(my_url, function(data){  $('#area').innerHTML(data); });
```

On success the element with an ID 'area' will be replaced with the new generated html response so that it looks 'real-time'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

```
$('#area').load(my_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by fastest, but the easiest is this:

```
$('#area').load(my_url);
```

Which does the same thing your `$.get` request does.

Comment: You were late for one second! ))) Type faster! =)